# Use React's high order component with more than one component as argument

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm fairly new to react-native (and React for this purpose) and I've just started working with high order components. I know that these are supposed to take **one** component as an argument an return **one** other component.

My issue here is that I would like my `HOC()` function to take **more than one** argument, i.e. something like `HOC:: C: React.Component, D: React.Component => H: React.Component`(in Haskell-like syntax).

Now, the problem (and reason why I'm posting this) is that it gives me a feeling that my code is a little clunky, because of the way I have to pass props. What I ended up doing is a function taking two arrays, a first array of components and a second one of props, that have to be given in the same order. (so that `propList[i]` is the `props` object of the component `componentList[i]`).

Something like (assuming all imports done):

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
  }
}
const HOC = (componentList, propsList) =>
class extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        {componentList.map( (Component, index) => {
          return <Component {...propsList[index]} />
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  render (){
    //this call is what makes me uncomfortable
    const DoubleComponent = HOC([MyComponent, MyComponent],[{name: 'first'}, {name: 'second'}]); 
    return(
      <DoubleComponent />
    )
  }
}
```

I've managed to build something like this and it works for what I want it to do, but this question was more about:

- **is it a bad thing ?** (I feel like this hurts composition as the props are specified in a different place, for instance)
- **if yes, what would you do instead?** (I have thought about currying but I wouldn't know how to implement it, especially if `HOC()` has to take an arbitrary number of components)

I'm also after any 'good practice tip' you guys could give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`props` are something that `HOC` can receive from the component props directly

```
const HOC = (componentList) =>

    class extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return(
          <View>
            {componentList.map( (Component, index) => {
              return <Component {...this.props[index]} />
            })}
          </View>
        )
      }

}
class App extends React.Component {
  render (){
    //this call is what makes me uncomfortable
    const DoubleComponent = HOC([MyComponent, MyComponent]); 
    return(
      <DoubleComponent names={[{name: 'first'}, {name: 'second'}]}/>
    )
  }
}
```